# Skype restores to non-existent area of desktop

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, skype

I've been using a desktop monitor with my laptop but now that I'm mobile Skype has presumably remembered it's position on a now non-existent area of the desktop rendering it unusable (which is the one reason I brought my laptop away from home in the first place!).

Any hints for restoring a window to a visible area of the desktop?

Comment: Probably worth reporting this as a bug to Skype, as well...

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - to be honest I'm more inclined to blame Vista for not forcing all windows onto the visible monitor once the previously attached monitor is gone. Surely Skype shouldn't have to pro-actively check for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not Skype-specific (although it's strange that the Skype taskbar entry doesn't show the 'Move' option which made me suspicious).

The answer is to [bring misplaced off-screen windows back to your desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/)...